# How to print a string backwards using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range, reverse

I have to create a program that lets the user enter a string and then, using range, the program outputs that same string backwards. I entered this into python, but it goes me an error, in the 4th line, it says `'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.
Can someone please help me correct it? (Using range)

```
user=raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
user1=len(user)-1
for user in range(user1,-1,-1):
    user2=user[user1]
    print user2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a mistake because you keep using the same words to describe very different data types. I would use a more descriptive naming scheme:

```
user = raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
user_length = len(user)
for string_index in range(user_length - 1, -1, -1):
    character = user[string_index]
    print(character)
```

For example, if the user input was `foo`, it would output:

```
o
o
f
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the user string with your for-loop, fix it by changing the for-loop variable

Fix:

```
for ind in range(user1,-1,-1):
    user2 = user[ind]
    print (user2)
```

Alternative (without for-loop):

```
print user[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are overwriting the string `user` with an int in the line `for user in range(...)`

Perhaps you'd be better off with:

```
user=raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
for user1 in range(len(user)-1,-1,-1):
    user2=user[user1]
    print user2
```

Answer (score 0):

your `user` has been overwrited in your for loop. Take this(Use range)

```
user=raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
print ''.join([user[i] for i in range(len(user)-1, -1, -1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 solution:

```
user=input("Please enter a string: ")
for ind in range(1,len(user)+1):
    char = user[-ind]
    print(char)
```

And another non for loop solution is:

```
''.join(reversed(user))
```